# How to show the last record of each customer for each month?

Tags: sql, teradata, teradatasql, history-tables

Please help, I have a table that contains the history of changes of the customer`s record for the last 3 years.
And I need to output the status or record of each customer for the "last day" of "each" month.

The table looks like this:

Table A:

```
| ID  | Name | Number|from_date(in Timestamp)|to_date(in Timestamp)|
|:--- |:----:|:-----:|----------------------:|--------------------:|
|123  | John | 101   |20210101 01:11:15      |20210103 01:11:15    | 
|123  | John | 102   |20210103 01:11:15      |20210301 01:11:15    | 
|123  | John | 103   |20210301 01:11:15      |20210325 01:11:15    | 
|123  | John | 104   |20210325 01:11:15      |20210415 01:11:15    | 
|123  | John | 105   |20210415 01:11:15      |20210416 01:11:15    | 
|123  | John | 106   |20210416 01:11:15      |20210525 01:11:15    |
|123  | John | 104   |20210525 01:11:15      |20210915 01:11:15    | 
|123  | John | 105   |20210915 01:11:15      |null                 |
```

Given the data above, unfortunately there is no record for month of Feb, June, July, August and September
but I need to show the data of the customers in "each" month (January to Decemeber).

The expected output should look like this:

```
| ID  | Name | Number|Date    |
|123  | John | 102   |20210131|
|123  | John | 102   |20210228|
|123  | John | 104   |20210331|
|123  | John | 106   |20210430|
|123  | John | 104   |20210531|
|123  | John | 104   |20210630|
|123  | John | 104   |20210731|
|123  | John | 104   |20210831|
|123  | John | 104   |20210931|
```

I can get the last day records of all the months which are visible in `from_date` column through the sql below.
but for the months which are not listed or months which are in between the `from_date` and `to_date` column, I am struggling to show it.

```
select a.id, a.name, a.number, last_day(a.from_date) Date
from (select a.*, row_number() over (partition by a.id, trunc(from_date, 'MON') 
order by from_date desc) as seqnum from tableA a
 ) a where seqnum = 1;
```

for your reference, above sql output looks like this:

```
| ID  | Name | Number|Date    |
|123  | John | 102   |20210131|
|123  | John | 104   |20210331|
|123  | John | 106   |20210430|
|123  | John | 106   |20210531|
|123  | John | 106   |20210931|
```

Comment: What's your Teradata release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Teradata's [EXPAND ON](https://docs.teradata.com/r/2_MC9vCtAJRlKle2Rpb0mA/mGTn1U7447PPxB52l5xONQ) clause. To do this, we create a `PERIOD` data type from your `from_date` and `to_date` and then use `EXPAND ON` to break that period into `MONTH_END` chunks.

This will look something like:

```
 SELECT yourtable.*, BEGIN(bg) 
 FROM yourtable
 EXPAND ON PERIOD(from_date, NEXT(to_date)) AS by BY ANCHOR MONTH_END;
```

May have to monkey with the syntax a bit there, but it should get you in the ballpark.

Answer (score 0):

TD 16.20+ supports so-called *time series aggregation*. This should return your expected result:

```
select id, name
  ,last(number)
  ,cast(end($TD_TIMECODE_RANGE) as date)
from table1
group by time(CAL_MONTHS(1) and id, name)
         using timecode (from_date) fill (previous)
```

Comment: Hi, this looks interesting! but I get an error: `No supported Time Series Aggregate function specified with the GROUP BY TIME clause.` do you know what might be the cause of it?

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing the actual SQL. Time Series don't support all standard aggregate functions: https://docs.teradata.com/r/mZqhP1sCTB4T74FbSzm7vA/lfWj_KMVYSDouOEUaoa1Hw

Comment: I will try to do some more testing if I can use the time series aggregation on my case. Thank you for the idea!

Comment: Hello, I have searched about Time series aggregate function and it looks like I have to convert my table into temporal table but I might be wrong. Do you have a sample table (table definition) where  I can use the above sql code?

Comment: You don't need a Time Series Table, `using timecode (from_date)` enables the usage of Time Series functions.